# How do you change graphics processing priority (idk what to call it)?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

So say I open an app on my pc (windows) and that app uses hardware acceleration, for example a browser like chrome. If chrome did something that required graphics, the first thing that would happen is that the CPU would try and do whatever chrome needed. But say chrome needed to do something graphics intensive that the cpu couldnt handle. Then the gpu would jump in, right? But what if I wanted the GPU to do that from the beginning, even if the CPU could do it itself?

But i dont know if what i said above is actually how it works. But i have done some research. I opened a app (epic games) and monitored my cpu/gpu usage. First I opened it in a small tab so that the resolution was low, so it didnt need a lot of graphics power. And I was right, my cpu was at abt 60% while my gpu was at 0% most of the time. Then i maximized the epic games window so that the resolution was 1440p. My cpu usage dropped to ~16% while my GPU bumped to abt ~20%. So my question is when epic games (or any other app) is in that windowed state where it doesnt require that much graphics power, do i make my gpu take priority over my cpu?

btw i have a cpu (intel, no igpu) and a dedicated gpu (amd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief answer - what you are trying to do likely can't be done by the end-user - it would need to be programmed into the application.  From a technical POV this is generally unlikely and unwarranted.

Your understanding of how this fits together is off a bit.   The CPU handles CPU instructions and the GPU handles things that require graphics (or that can and are programmed to be offloaded to the graphics processor in the case of more powerful GPU's and tasks that lend themselves to parallelization)

The GPU and CPU work hand in hand.  While the CPU does hand off tasks to the GPU, it does this based on the task, not on how busy the CPU is.   These decisions are often done in an abstraction layer (ie software library) depending on the capabilities of the GPU.  **In other words the GPU is doing this from the beginning if it is able to do so**

I expect your interpretation of your test is a little flawed - A likely reason for the difference is that when in a window your OS is a lot more involved in drawing other parts of the screen, and these elements are CPU bound - and its possible that because it was in a Window the CPU was being used for calculating the graphics as well.     When you switched to full screen mode, the GPU didn't kick in because it was needed for the additional processor, it kicked in because it was able to take control of the screen as the CPU was not needed to drive the window manager.

Comment: okie dokie tyty i sorta understand now